# Difference between null terminated char (\0) and `^@`

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, char

My codes are like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << (int)('\0') << endl;
    cout << (char)(0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to see in terminal like this:

```
$ test-program
0

$
```

However, what I saw is like this:

```
$ test-program
0
^@
$
```

What makes me confusing is that I think `'\0'` can be converted to `0`. And `0` can also be casted into `\0`. I expected to see a null char followed with a `endl`, but the result is something weird like `^@`.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: I got the expected result in Windows (compiled with MinGW gcc).

Comment: Use `| hexdump -C` to see the hexadecimal output. This way you make sure *your program* does what you expect it to do, so it's *the terminal* which behaves not as (you) expected.

Comment: this is c++, then type matters. in first case it is an integer 0 that has to be displayed, then 0 is converted to test "0". In second case it is a real character 0 which is really a character 0. .test-programm > result. use emacs with --hexl-mode, it will then confirm that. second point is terminal display of character 0 that can vary, in your case character 0 ( which normaly should never be displayed since in C its ends a string ) will be displayed as ^@.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`^@` is just how your terminal emulator renders `'\0'`.

Answer (score 7):

`^@` is a common representation of a null character. Similarly, `^A` is used to represent a character with ordinal value 1, `^G` for the character with ordinal value 7 (bell), and `^M` for the character with ordinal value 13 (Carriage return).

```
cout << (char)0
```

Is just printing the character representation, rather than the integer representation

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at your terminal's output, you don't know if it's your program which doesn't behave as expected or maybe just your terminal emulator.

On UNIXoid systems, use `./myProgram | hexdump -C` to see the hexadecimal output. This way you make sure *your program* does what you expect it to do, so it's *the terminal* which behaves not as (you) expected:

```
00000000  30 0a 00 0a                                       |0...|
00000004
```

If you see the same output than I do, you're actually printing a zero `'0'`, newline `'\n'`, null `'\0'`, newline `'\n'`. So in this case, your program behaves as you've expected.

You might want to try different terminal emulators or settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast `0` to `char`, it doesn't generate `'0'`, but `'\0'` -- keep in mind casting from an integral type to `char` creates a `char` with that ASCII code.
So basically, the second line is outputting a null character (ASCII 0).

If you wanted to output a `'0'` char, you would have needed to do something like `(char) 48`, because 48 happens to be the ASCII value for the character 0.

Comment: The OP is aware that he is printing null character, or at least I think he does from the way he writes the question.

Comment: then first line is wrong since in that case it is displaying the zero integer, wich is not same as zero char.