# Wierd result (`\210`) when printing the end of a char array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, char

My codes are like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ca[] = {'0'};
    cout << *ca << endl;
    cout << *(ca+1) << endl;
    cout << ca[1] << endl;
    cout << (char)(0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is like this:

```
 0
 \210
 \210
 ^@
```

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795565/difference-between-null-terminated-char-0-and), I knew that `^@` is the same as `\0` actually. However, the `\210` seems not because when I use `hexdump` to view the result.

```
 bash-3.2$ ./playground | hexdump -C
 00000000  30 0a 88 0a 88 0a 00 0a                           |0.......|
 00000008
```

It can be seen clearly that `\210` is `88` instead of `00`.

As I understood, `ca+1` should point to a `null terminator`, which is `\0`. But why `cout << *(ca+1) << endl;` gives me `\210` as the result?

Comment: Try `char ca[] = "0";`, then read aaaaaa123456789`s answer for why it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have to manually add the null terminator when declaring a character **array**. If you make it a **string** (such as in `char myString[] = "hi"`), then it will add a null terminator. But if you make it an **array**, with the braces, it will not.

As for the 0x88 byte, it just happened to be the next byte in RAM for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

In any valid C program the string literals are always null terminated. Here you are trying to initialize the individual element of character array but just with list initialization syntax  and not to a string literal. As this is static array allocated with in same function, you can even confirm this with help of sizeof operator.
doing `ca` should give you 1 i.e. one character array. However if you would have done something like `char ca[] = "0";` then applying `sizeof(ca)` should give you 2 i.e. character '0' and null termination character. As aaaaaa123456789 mentioned, this is just an output now you are getting, just another byte in a memory. If you run this at some different time, you will see different output or your program may crash. referring incorrect location may cause any runtime anomaly.